Calculating the odds of the On Numara Turkish lottery
Ok, either I'm doing something wrong (most probably), I'm not understanding the rules (probably), or something's going on which I can't understand.
As per the rules here (untranslated), The On Numera (or Ten Number) Turkish lottery has the following rules:

22 numbers are drawn from a pool of 80
Hit 10 of those 22 numbers gets you the jackpot.

So, as per another question I asked before, and this paper, I understand it's basically a 10 out of 22 from 1 to 80 problem, or, in other words, "10 numbers guessed correctly out of 22 drawn from a pool of 1 to 80". So, to quote:
"To match k of the winning numbers, we must select k of 6 winning numbers AND we must select (6 − k) of the 43 non-winning numbers."
which I now rephrase to the following:
"To match 10 of the winning numbers, we must select 10 of 22 winning numbers AND we must select (22 − 10) of the 58 non-winning numbers."
In Excel:
Therefore there are COMBIN(22,10) x COMBIN(58, 12) possible winning tickets matching 10 of the winning numbers.
So:
COMBIN(80,22) = (an astronomical) 27,088,786,024,742,600,000
COMBIN(22,10) = 646,646
COMBIN(58,12) = 891,794,789,340
Multiply 646,646 by 891,794,789,340 gets us 576,675,533,347,554,000
Divide 27,088,786,024,742,600,000 by 576,675,533,347,554,000 gets me 47.
What am I doing wrong? I can't believe that is a 1 in 47 chance (to win). That seems utterly impossible!
What am I not understanding or, better even, what operation am I doing wrong?
Any help is most welcome!

Please take the time to format your questions properly.  here is a good guide to formatting for this site.

should also say:  I can't sort out the rules of the lottery.  How many numbers does a contestant choose?  How is a winner determined?

The, the number of numbers a player chooses is kind of important.

That's why I said: I understand it's basically a 10 out of 22 from 1 to 80 problem. Let's go with that.

My guess (aided by google translate) is:  $22$ out of $80$ numbers have been chosen in secret.  A contestant chooses $10$ numbers out of the $80$ and wins if all $10$ guesses happen to be among the secret $22$.  My confidence level in this guess is low.

"A 10 out of 22 from 1 to 80 problem" is not a standard term, so I have no idea what that means. Just tell us. I'm not clicking t9 a link t9 a paper of unknown length with no idea where in the paper I can find the term.

10 numbers guessed correctly out of 22 drawn from a pool of 1 to 80.

Put it in the question. Readers shouldn't have to read the comments to understand your question.

If my guess is correct (doubtful, to put it kindly) then there are $\binom {22}{10}$ winning guesses out of a possible $\binom {80}{10}$ guesses.  The ratio of those is a dismal $\frac {119}{302998180}\sim 3.93\times 10^{-7}$.

From the internet, what I get is that from $80$ numbers, you have to pick $22$, and if all $10$ prize winning numbers are present in your $22$, you get the grand prize. (Lesser prizes for $9$ correct, $8$ correct, etc are also available)
Focusing on the grand prize, the probability of getting it is very very  low, $\dfrac{\binom{22}{10}}{\binom{80}{10}}, \approx 1\; in\; 2.55\; million$

Thank you for your insight, true blue anil. However, if you see the website, there are in effect 22 numbers drawn in each drawing. On point 2.2, it says (translated): 2.2 A game combination consists of ten numbers between 1 to 80 (included). Anyways, for the sake of going forward, let's suppose that 22 numbers are in effect drawn (from a pool of 80), and the user has to select 10 (and hit 10 from 22 drawn). Can you please explain (if not too much trouble) what the odds would be, and how the calculation would look like?

@Molasar49: If you have to select $10$ from $22$ drawn, (i.e. you know the $22$ drawn), there can be $\binom{22}{10}$ possible choices out of which only $1$ will be correct, with $Pr = \dfrac{1}{\binom{22}{10}}= 1; in; 646646$ of winning

The computation in which non-winning numbers are factored in is,for example, for  a simple $49/6$ lotto where in the $6$ you choose from $49$, some may be correct, and some wrong, e.g. for $4$ correct, $\dfrac{\binom64\binom{43}2}{\binom{49}{6}}= \dfrac{645}{665896}$
